# pyspark --number of columns are different in some rows. need to get the aggregate

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

{1-jan-21 10:00,log1, 404, not_found, 11.12.13.14}
{1-jan-21 10:30,log1,server1, 404, not_found, 11.12.13.14}

{1-jan-21 12:00, 505, internal_error, 12.12.13.14}
{1-jan-21 13:00,log2, 404, not_found, 13.12.13.14}

output
http_error_code, count
404 , 3
505 , 1

Answer (score 0):

You havent provided how are you reading the data so assuming you can read all data as a single array you can use below array_intersect way by adding other possible error codes on right array and count those

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import * 
tdf=spark.createDataFrame([(["1-jan-21 10:00","log1", 404, "not_found", "11.12.13.14"],),
(["1-jan-21 10:30","log1","server1", 404, "not_found", "11.12.13.14"],),
(["1-jan-21 12:00", 505, "internal_error", "12.12.13.14"],),
(["1-jan-21 13:00","log2", 404, "not_found", "13.12.13.14"],)]).toDF("tery")
tdf.withColumn("cextr",array_intersect("tery",array([lit("404"),lit("505")]))).groupBy("cextr").agg(count("cextr").alias("count")).show()

+-----+-----+
|cextr|count|
+-----+-----+
|[505]|    1|
|[404]|    3|
+-----+-----+
```